# Haskell pattern matching symmetric cases

Tags: haskell, syntax, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a haskell expression like:

```
foo (Nothing, Just a) = bar a
foo (Just a, Nothing) = bar a
```

Is there any haskell syntax to collapse those cases, so I can match either pattern and specify `bar a` as the response for both?  Or is that about as succinct as I can get it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914965/patterns-for-symmetric-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's as succinct as it gets in Haskell. In ML there is a syntax for what you want (by writing multiple patterns, which bind the same variables, next to each other separated by `|` with the body after the last pattern), but in Haskell there is not.

Answer (score 8):

If your code is more complex than your example, you might want to do something like this, using the `Alternative` instance for `Maybe` and the `PatternGuards` extension (part of Haskell2010).

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}
import Control.Applicative

foo (x, y) | Just a <- y <|> x = bar a
```

In case you are not familiar with it, `<|>` picks the left-most `Just` if there is one and returns `Nothing` otherwise, causing the pattern guard to fail.

Comment: an important caveat though - this matches more cases than the original code.  foo (Just x, Just y) would be matched, so if that's not what you want you'd have to make sure to handle it in an earlier case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-XViewPatterns`, to add arbitrary functions to collapse your two cases into a single pattern.
Your pattern is now a function `p` that yields the thing you want to match:

```
foo (p -> (Just a, Nothing)) = bar a
```

much simpler!

We have to define `p` though, as:

```
p (Nothing, a@(Just _)) = (a, Nothing)
p a@(Just _,   Nothing) = a
p a                     = a
```

or however you wish to normalize the data before viewing.

---

*References:* The [GHC User's Guide chapter on View Patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns)